# Как значений в таблицы вычислить среднее значение?

Tags: delphi, sql

Берутся данные температуры с Firebird на каждый день каждые 5 минут, как можно из данных в таблице на день вывести в другой ну тот же Grid вывести среднесуточное значение на каждый день? Не понимаю просто как отельные значения выбирать и вычислять еще и выводить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В запросе нужно делать группировку записей по дате (без учета времени) и использовать агрегатную функцию `AVG()`. В MySQL  это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
SELECT DATE(tablename.datetime), AVG(tablename.value)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Не совсем то мне нужно на выходе таблицу, со среднесуточным значением, где по горизонтали числа от 1 до 31 а вертикали меся от 1 до 12, итого это получается таблица на год. вообщем примерно такого вида - http://rghost.ru/32318341/image.png
Хотя может как то сделать процедуру на базе которая вычисляет уже среднесуточное? но я не знаю как

Comment: Запрос возвращает подготовленную информацию с среднесуточным значением за каждый день, а вывод в подходящем виде нужно делать на стороне приложения. Проходишься по источнику данных от начала до конца и раскидуешь информацию по ячейкам StringGrid-а.

Comment: Ага отлично я понял спасибо. и последний вопрос раз уж так что бы новый не делать.
Как вывести это же с первого числа выбраного месяца до первого числа следующего месяца. ну то есть

SELECT WEATHER.DATE, AVG(WEATHER.TEMP)
FROM WEATHER
WHERE WEATHER.DATE >= (01.01.2011) and WEATHER.DATE < (01.02.2011
GROUP BY 1

например так, ну то бишь с выбраного месяца до следующего.